# Different listed times of tzeit hakochavim

Tags: halacha, zemanim, evening-night

Tzeit hakochavim is an important time of day. For instance, as far as I know it is the earliest time for Shema in the evening. I've seen many calculations of that  time (nine are displayed on myzmanim.com and there might be more that aren't). Are there halachic sources which pertain to the question of how tzeit hakochavim should be calculated? What is the basis for the differing calculations?

Comment: I wrote out a long answer to this question with numerous sources and references to different approaches, and I will post it when the "on hold" status has been removed. Perhaps it can be re-worded as a request for relevant sources.